# Jackson unwrap object in array

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

Hi I have some JSON which is wrapped as so:

```
{
  rootNode: [{
    "property":"value"
  }]
}
```

Is there a way of getting the object in the array as:

```
@JsonRootName("rootNode")
public class ThisClass{
  private String property;
}
```

If there is no array I can just use the rootnode notation are there any other annotations to compensate for the wrapped array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parse this JSON by enabling the following deserialization options in jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS);
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features#structural-conversions) for details

Answer (score 2):

Was able to get this working by setting some options on ObjectMapper

```
mapper
.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true),
.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS);
```